# Why won't the php receive the data in ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Why do I get this error?

The php won't receive the data in ajax.

[image: The php won't receive the data in ajax]

this is the php code

```
<?php

echo $_POST['name'];

?>
```

this is the source

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

this is the code for the script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#name').keyup(function(x){
    var name = $('#name').val();

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "insert.php",
        data :{name : name},

        success: function(){
            alert (name);
                $('#info').load('insert .php')
        }

    });

    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, just make sure your element "#info" is a div or span. Use .val(data) if it is a textbox.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    data :{'name' : name},

    success: function(data){
        alert (data);
            $('#info').html(data);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must check if you actually have `$_POST['name']` set, and only then use it:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
?>
```

Comment: wont get error but the problem is still there the php file wont receive the data

Answer (score 0):

You should use `method:"POST"` in place of `type:"POST"`. Otherwise JQuery will default to sending a GET request and you won't have that in PHP's global $_POST variable. `type` works with versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0. See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: how about you add an `error ` callback among the options to see whats triggering it

Comment: the error is inside the ajax 
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: "insert.php",
    
    error : alert("err"),
    data :{name : name},
    success: function(data){
        alert (data);
            $('#info').load("insert.php");
    }

});

Comment: try `error: function(err){ console.error('ajax error ', err); },`